# Weird issue with XLC++ 11.1

Tags: c++, aix, xlc

Maybe this was a case of bad programming, but it is manifesting itself with the upgrade of XLC++ from 6.0 to 11.1

The code looks like :

```
     int startAt = 140;
 startAt = parseAndSaveResponseINSTANTID_MODEL(response, startAt);
 COUT << "After tokenize INSTANTID_MODEL startAt=" <<startAt <<ENDL;

    startAt = startAt++;
    startAt = parseAndSaveResponseINSTANTID_CHRON_HISTORY(response, startAt);
COUT << "After tokenize INSTANTID_MODEL startAt=" <<startAt <<ENDL;

    startAt = startAt++;
    startAt = parseAndSaveResponseINSTANTID_FOLLOWUP_ACTION(response, startAt);
COUT << "After tokenize TSTID_INSTANTID_FOLLOWUP_ACTION startAt=" <<startAt <<ENDL;

startAt = startAt++;
    startAt = parseAndSaveResponseINSTANTID_RISK_INDICATOR(response, startAt);
COUT << "After tokenize TSTID_INSTANTID_RISK_INDICATOR startAt=" <<startAt <<ENDL;
```

And within each of the parse methods, we do a `return (startAt + 1 + vRows * 81);`

vRows is zero in all methods.

With the old compiler, the output looks like :

```
 After tokenize INSTANTID_MODEL startAt=141
 vRows=0
 After tokenize INSTANTID_MODEL startAt=142
 vRows=0
 After tokenize TSTID_INSTANTID_FOLLOWUP_ACTION startAt=143
 vRows=0
 After tokenize TSTID_INSTANTID_RISK_INDICATOR startAt=144
```

But, with the new compiler, the output looks like

```
 After tokenize INSTANTID_MODEL startAt=141
 vRows=0
 After tokenize INSTANTID_MODEL startAt=143
 vRows=0
 After tokenize TSTID_INSTANTID_FOLLOWUP_ACTION startAt=145
 vRows=0
 After tokenize TSTID_INSTANTID_RISK_INDICATOR startAt=147
```

Was there a change in the way integers/returns are handled?

Comment: `startAt = startAt++` - `parseAndSaveResponseINSTANTID_MODEL()` - `COUT` - `ENDL`... dude, you don't only have problems with the code, you also have a problem with the coders / architects / QS people on this project...

Comment: COUT and ENDL are typedefs of std::cout and std::endl. And yes, this is not a very oft used part of the code, and has been missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startAt = startAt++` is [undefined behaviour](http://c-faq.com/expr/ieqiplusplus.html). Because it's undefined, a compiler is at liberty to give any result it feels like giving, like this result in version 6.0 and a different one in version 11.1.

;-)

With GCC, `-Wsequence-point` (or `-Wall`) would emit a warning for this construct. Not sure if there is an equivalent warning in XLC.